# SimpleForm select to not include a blank (by default)

Tags: forms, simple-form

To have a select box omit the blank option you can do:

```
:include_blank => false
```

In Formtastic, there's a config option that allows you to do this by default:

```
Formtastic::FormBuilder.include_blank_for_select_by_default = false
```

Is the a way to configure this in SimpleForm too?  I haven't been able to find it in the docs or anything...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry but you can't do this with Simple Form right now. There was a [pull request](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/pull/219) adding this feature but it wasn't merged. If you want to add it to Simple Form pull request is more than welcome.